# WebView in Lollipop doesn't load fonts from assets

Tags: android, html, webview, assets, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using a `WebView` to render some html content. In my CSS I have the following code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: CharterC;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("asset://fonts/CharterC.otf");
}
```

And I have the following Java code in my `WebViewClient`:

```
    @Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith(ASSETS_SCHEME)) {
        String asset = url.substring(ASSETS_SCHEME.length());
        if (asset.endsWith(".js")) {
            try {
                return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "utf-8", context.getAssets().open(asset));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (asset.endsWith(".ttf") || asset.endsWith(".otf")) {
            try {
                return new WebResourceResponse("font/" + MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(asset), "utf-8", context.getAssets().open(asset)); // this will produce MimeType like: font/ttf
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
   }
}
```

And this code works very well in Android 4.1–4.4, but in Android 5.0 this code loads the js, but fails to load fonts, and I see the following message in webkit console:

> Font from origin 'asset://' has been blocked from loading by
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

How can I load fonts from assets on Android 5.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the new [WebResourceResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html#WebResourceResponse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E,%20java.io.InputStream%29) constructor to set the HTTP headers to pass along with the intercepted request.

As the new constructor was only introduced in Lollipop, make sure to check the SDK version at runtime.

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("fonts/myfontasset.ttf");
WebResourceResponse response = null;
String encoding= "UTF-8";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    int statusCode = 200;
    String reasonPhase = "OK";
    Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    responseHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    response = new WebResourceResponse("font/ttf", encoding, statusCode, reasonPhase, responseHeaders, inputStream);
} else {
    response = new WebResourceResponse("font/ttf", encoding, inputStream);
}
```

Note: You must build against SDK Level 21 at least.